# Getting Vs code to connect to remote repo

Tags: git, bash, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

This may seem like a repeat question but i have tried EVERYTHING and nothing seems to be working, im using VS Team Services with VS Code. I have successfuly copied the repo to my desktop and am trying to "PUSH" it to the online repo from vs code. However whener i click push it askes for me to authenticate my username and password. Ive typed in so many different variations and nothing works. I do have alternate authentication credentials check, I have tried to use these to log in, it didn't work.

I tried the `$ git config --global credential.helper wincred` when i type this in using Git Bash it doesnt do anything.
[image]

Please i could really use some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled everything and reinstalled and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to remote repo, you can connect to the Git project, then in Team Explorer -- Setting -- Git -- Repository Settings, add remote. After that, you can push the commits to remote repo.